# Joint actuator consideration for quadruple robot

Tags: motor, actuator

I’m in the process of building a hybrid robot between wheel and leg so that it could traverse different terrain effectively. I’m not planning to implement any complicate galloping or jumping on my robot, I just want the system to be robust enough to climb stairs and crawl through some uneven surface where wheels are too unstable. To make the discussion easier, my robot weights around 2kg at the moment and it resembles a rectangular box.

I’ve started working on designing the legs a few days ago and realized that off-the-shelf BLDC actuators on AliExpress is really pricey (the MIT mini cheetah’s one is about 400 AUD, cheaper BLDC is about 90$ but I’m not sure whether it will worth my money or not). Buying 12 of these are a big investment so I have to take caution. Servos are another high torque and simple solution, however I’m not confident that their control and motion are smooth enough to remain balance mid-climb.

I’ve also considered building my own BLDC actuators using the PCB stator technology so that I could reduce cost and weight, however, there aren’t too many documentations and resource about this fairly new tech to support my design process. I’m currently gravitating toward making my own actuator this way, given that pcb are fairly cheap to make.

Well, there’s a lot to consider and I’ve put my head onto this for days. I’m very glad to hear your opinions on this problem!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: this is a question and answer site, it is not a forum for soliciting opinions ... as such, requesting opinions is off topic here ... please add a clear, answerable question to your post